# Searching for a file reference

Tags: shell, unix

I have a checkout of code within a directory on my Unix box>

I need to compared two files to see how they are referenced throughout the code. So this would involve searching through the directories and then searching through the files.

so I'm somewhat of the way there

```
search through files within the folder structure | grep "myReference" | less
```

The problem is I do not know an efficient way of doing the first bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -nir 'myReference' .` | less

Answer (score 0):

```
 grep -nr "Search term" /path/to/files/
```